# Jquery drag & drop to iframe and sort inside of it

Tags: jquery, sorting, iframe, drag-and-drop, positioning

I want to drag and drop element into iframe and sort it inside the iframe

Here is my code :

```
<div class="draggable">
   <img class="img" width="50%" src="http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg">
</div>

<iframe id="phone-iframe" width="100%" height="100%" src="iframe.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#phone-iframe').load(function () {
        $('#phone-iframe').contents().find('.sortable').sortable({
            connectWith: ".sortable",
            revert: true
        });
        $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
            connectToSortable: $('#phone-iframe').contents().find('.sortable'),
            iframeFix: true,
            helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid",
            zIndex: 2,
            opacity: 0.74,
            appendTo: 'body',
            distance: 15
        });
    });
});
```

Iframe code :

```
<ul class="sortable">
  <li>I'm sortable</li>
  <li>Me too</li></ul>
```

It is working but there is a position problem on iframe. It's not working when you drag inside to the iframe (if i change to iframe position to 0px X 0px it works. )

Here is my code : http://tekdogru.com/iframexample/

Comment: Can you perhaps make a fiddle? Is there any specific reason it needs to be in an iFrame?

Comment: Yes iframe is necessary, I'll use jqmobile inside of it. I tried fiddle but I couldn't create the same example with iframe because of the origin policy things..

Comment: Here's a fiddle if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/PYeLh/
It's something to do with the `float` CSS properties

Comment: Drag is not working on fiddle, you should check on my URL

Comment: Drag is working in fiddle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a code which is a great solution for jQuery UI's drag into iframe problem, add this code into your jquery ui file and it works.

```
// Create new object to cache iframe offsets
$.ui.ddmanager.frameOffsets = {};
// Override the native `prepareOffsets` method. This is almost
// identical to the un-edited method, except for the last part!
$.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets = function (t, event) {
var i, j,
    m = $.ui.ddmanager.droppables[t.options.scope] || [],
    type = event ? event.type : null, // workaround for #2317
    list = (t.currentItem || t.element).find(":data(ui-droppable)").addBack(),
    doc, frameOffset;

droppablesLoop: for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {

    //No disabled and non-accepted
    if (m[i].options.disabled || (t && !m[i].accept.call(m[i].element[0], (t.currentItem || t.element)))) {
        continue;
    }

    // Filter out elements in the current dragoged item
    for (j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        if (list[j] === m[i].element[0]) {
            m[i].proportions().height = 0;
            continue droppablesLoop;
        }
    }

    m[i].visible = m[i].element.css("display") !== "none";
    if (!m[i].visible) {
        continue;
    }

    //Activate the droppable if used directly from draggables
    if (type === "mousedown") {
        m[i]._activate.call(m[i], event);
    }

    // Re-calculate offset
    m[i].offset = m[i].element.offset();

    // Re-calculate proportions (jQuery UI ~1.10 introduced a `proportions` cache method, so support both here!)
    proportions = { width: m[i].element[0].offsetWidth, height: m[i].element[0].offsetHeight };
    typeof m[i].proportions === 'function' ? m[i].proportions(proportions) : (m[i].proportions = proportions);

    /* ============ Here comes the fun bit! =============== */

    // If the element is within an another document...
    if ((doc = m[i].document[0]) !== document) {
        // Determine in the frame offset using cached offset (if already calculated)
        frameOffset = $.ui.ddmanager.frameOffsets[doc];
        if (!frameOffset) {
            // Calculate and cache the offset in our new `$.ui.ddmanager.frameOffsets` object
            frameOffset = $.ui.ddmanager.frameOffsets[doc] = $(
                // Different browsers store it on different properties (IE...)
                (doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow).frameElement
            ).offset();
        }

        // Add the frame offset to the calculated offset
        m[i].offset.left += frameOffset.left;
        m[i].offset.top += frameOffset.top;
    }
}
};
```

Here is the source : http://blog.craigsworks.com/jquery-ui-draggable-droppables-in-an-iframe/

Comment: kind of an old answer.. But the problem still exists in jQuery UI. using this code, it kind of works better, but the iframe scroll positions are not taken care of. Any chance this can be added?